# From external program, append cell, execute, and show output in a running Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

My desired outcome is to be able to modify an existing Jupyter notebook running in the browser, live, from another program.

The other program (say a local editor) that has access to the kernel/back end of notebook should be able to call an api to append a cell with specified contents, execute the cell, and show the output. This would allow me to implement "send to notebook" functionality in an editor.

The examples for programmatically doing seem to require running in the notebook itself. I would like to be able to just send code to be executed to the kernel, and have it output the result in the already running jupyter notebook. This should not require refreshing the page or anything like that, ideally.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dh5dtKDWgyM

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.